# Customize package for QueryDSL output

Tags: java, mongodb, maven-3, querydsl

I am creating QueryDSL objects for MongoDB using Maven, here's the build xml,

```
<build>
        <sourceDirectory>src/main/java</sourceDirectory>
        <testSourceDirectory>src/test/java</testSourceDirectory>
        <plugins>                
            <plugin>
                <groupId>com.mysema.maven</groupId>
                <artifactId>maven-apt-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>1.0</version>
                <executions>
                    <execution>
                        <phase>generate-sources</phase>
                        <goals>
                            <goal>process</goal>
                        </goals>
                    </execution>
                </executions>
                <configuration>
                    <outputDirectory>src/main/java</outputDirectory>
                    <!-- This processor uses the Spring MongoDB annotations for processing -->
                    <processor>org.springframework.data.mongodb.repository.support.MongoAnnotationProcessor</processor>                        
                </configuration>
            </plugin>
        </plugins>
    </build>
```

But its generating the query class `QDomain` for `Domain` in the same package as `Domain`.

Can the plugin be customized to put Query classes in a separate package?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can use the querydsl.packageSuffix APT option to add a suffix to your generated package. Just add the following block inside configuration

```
<options>
    <querydsl.packageSuffix>.query</querydsl.packageSuffix>
</options>
```

Comment: Is there a similar config option for the querydsl-maven-plugin?